# How can make multiple factor columns with different levels ordered?

Tags: r

I plan to carry out Wilcoxon rank sum test for a survey result.
Now I have data

```
data <- data.frame(
  q2s1 = factor(c(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4)),
  q2s2 = factor(c(3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3)),
  q16 = factor(c(3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2)),
  sex = factor(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
)
```

They are all factor variables with different levels.
Acuatully, these variables are just a small part of my actual variables.
My outcome variables are variables containing "s" in the column names, q11, q12 and q16.
In order to carry out test, I need to make these variables ordered.
Thus, how can I achieve it with less time?
BTW, can I just convert these factor variables into numeric class to carry out test?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the correct order is numerical order, you can just do:

```r
data[]  <- lapply(data, \(x) factor(x, ordered = TRUE))
```

Each column will now be an ordered factor, e.g.

```r
data$q2s1
# [1] 3 1 1 2 2 4
# Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4
```

If the order is different, you can specify it, e.g.:

```r
fct_levels  <- c(3,1,2,4,5)
data[]  <- lapply(data, \(x) factor(x, levels = fct_levels, ordered = TRUE))
```

The levels will be in the order set out in `fct_levels`:

```r
data$q2s1
# [1] 3 1 1 2 2 4
# Levels: 3 < 1 < 2 < 4 < 5
```

As to whether you can convert the variables to numeric for Wilcoxon rank sum test, that's a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Basically though, the answer is it depends. Generally you need to consider how the data is distributed, and what the values mean. If they are something like Likert scores, is it reasonable to assume that the difference between 1 and 2 is the same as the difference between 4 and 5? See e.g. [Analyzing the results of Likert scale with one sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547541/analyzing-the-results-of-likert-scale-with-one-sample-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test).

#### Response to question in comments

If you only want to make some columns ordered factors, just apply this to a subset of columns:

```r
cols_to_order <- c("q2s1", "q2s2")
data[cols_to_order] <- lapply(data[cols_to_order], \(x) factor(x, ordered = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Please allow me to ask more about this. It seems that data[]  <- lapply(data, \(x) factor(x, ordered = TRUE)) will make all columns ordered, but I also have some binary variables such as sex and death, then if binary ones become ordered ones, does this matter to the test?

Comment: @NKevin better not to make columns ordered that you don't want to be - see my edit.

Comment: Now I meet new problems, after I code this:
`subwil_p <- function(outc, var){
  data %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    wilcox_test(as.formula(paste(outc, var, sep = " ~ ")))
}

subwil_p("sex","q2s1")`, and it returned `Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
i With name: V1.
Caused by error in `wilcox.test.default()`:
! 'x' must be numeric`. How can I solve it?

Comment: @NKevin I am not sure - I am not familiar with the `wilcox_test()` function. Is it from `rstatix`? As this seems to be about that rather than making data into a factor, I think it would be best to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to find other reference.